# <xsl:variable name="descrip" select="substring(Descripcion,1,90)"/> with disable-output-scaping

Tags: xslt

```
<xsl:variable name="descrip"  select="substring(Descripcion,1,90)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

thats it this doesn't compile is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, there isn't any "workaround".**

**[DOE is only defined in the XSLT specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#disable-output-escaping)** for `<xsl:value-of>` and for `<xsl:text>`